# References don't show up in Visual Studio 2017 after creating a .NET Standard branch

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2017

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017 on the open-source project https://github.com/SpiegelSoft/XamarinForms.Reactive.FSharp

I recently created a branch called dotnet-standard, which, as its name suggests, is a migration to .NET Standard. However, after creating this branch and checking back in to the master branch, which is a PCL rather than a .NET standard library, the project will no longer build.

First of all, the references are not visible. All I can see in Visual Studio is a .NET node (see screenshot).

The build fails in the first instance with

> Xamarin.Forms targets have been imported multiple times. Please check your project file and remove the duplicate import(s).

This is odd because the same fsproj file was working before I created the new branch.

When I delete the Xamarin.Forms import line in my fsproj file and then perform a `git reset --hard`, the error message changes to

> Your project is not referencing the ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259" framework. Add a reference to ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.

But the IDE won't even let me a a project.json file. Something has clearly gone very wrong with my Visual Studio settings.

Does anyone have any obvious tips before I reinstall Visual Studio?

[image]

Comment: I'd try a `git clean -xfd` in addition to your reset. Assuming your `.gitignore` file is configured correctly, this should remove any temp files that MSBuild and VS may have created that might be throwing it off.

Comment: That worked, after a bit of fiddling. If you want to submit it as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

As alluded in the comments, VS / MS Build can trip up on previously generated files - often in the various `obj` folders.

To get back to a ‘clean’ state (the same as when you first clone a repo), run `git reset —hard` to revert any uncommitted changes and `git clean -xfd` to remove any untracked files and folders.

Assuming your `.gitignore` file is configured correctly, this last step should remove all temporary files.